# Is always normalizing features standard practice?

Tags: machine-learning

It seems like every single machine learning method (perceptron, SVM, etc) warns you about the need to normalize all the features during preprocessing.

Is this always true for all common machine learning methods? Or am I just running into the few that require normalized features.

Comment: It's not always needed (e,g, Random-forests don't care in general). But the theory behind SVM-training and for example stochastic-gradient descent likes normalized data.

Comment: @sascha just to make things clear - SGD is actually just a first-order optimizer, not ML method as such, thus it does not "like normalized data", but some models, that are often trained with SGD - like it.

Comment: @lejlot Thanks for the comment. Do you have anything to read regarding this? I would have expected SGD will behave more stable if using with normalized data (one "wrong" move into bad "direction" should hurt more, if data is not normalized), regarding estimation-error or maybe optimization-error (i'm not sure).

Comment: @sascha, you are right that SGD likes "nice surface" the problem is there is no relation between data normalization (in feature space) and such behavior. You can google for "natural networks" or in general - Fisher-based optimization, which tries to capture this feature in well defined mathematical sense.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is a good idea to normalize since many ML methods need it, and other do not care at all (thus you do not harm the process). The only exception is methods crafted for a very specific types of data (especially if you have features that represent completely different classes of objects, and have a specialistic method which is aware of that, for example a kernel that treats differently dates and 'regular' numbers).